# How to Customize GridView in android

Tags: android, gridview

I want to customize the GridView layout.I want the GridView to look like the snapshot provided below:-

[App Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsfDi.jpg)

Here is my GridView layout:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:background="#fff">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_id_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_name_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/divder_color"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_discount_grid_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="1891" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_special_grid_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="1891"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/products_price_grid_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/products_off_grid_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:rating="0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my layout where I access GridView :-

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/list_product_grid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/products_page_grid_view"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dp"/>
```

Can anyone help me how I make my GridView look like the image above. I am new to Android .Please help me .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class extends BaseAdapter,and inflate your xml layout for each row in `getView` and set data.You can refer this:https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html,not same as you want,but I think you will know how to make it as you want after reading this.

I suggest you use [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead of GridView,which has more efficient performances and flexible layout managers.

Comment: Which page link you give me this is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [`GridLayoutManager`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) with [`RecyclerView`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) for making UI that you shown in the link and it will be more flexible to do any related operation such as adding,removing items etc.`RecyclerView` have built in animations and no need to worry about reusing view too.you might need to use [`CardView`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) as a grid item.

Follow any one of the tutorial to achieve that

[Link 1](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/)

[Link 2](http://www.exoguru.com/android/ui/recyclerview/custom-android-grids-using-recyclerview.html)

[Link 3](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html)

[Link 4](http://itnavdev.blogspot.in/2015/04/recyclerview.html)

Find the sample usage of [CardView along with RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView).

Answer (score 0):

try this code for your grid_item_layout by replacing your drawables,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_grid_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/"your product drawable name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/new_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image_grid_view"
            android:background="#666666"
            android:text="New"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bookmark_text_view"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/image_grid_view"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/image_grid_view"
            android:src="@drawable/your bookmark or favourite drawable name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_id_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TOPSHOP"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_name_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Rs.3990"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```